# How to display a figure on a determinated section

Tags: floats, sectioning, article, figure-placement

I'm writing an article with a two-column distribution. I want to display some images that need to be shown almost as wide as the page and centered, specifically in the Results section. The problem is, when I compile the document it shows the figures anywhere they "suit" as default.
I'm using the following code

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{imágenes/Np-Ng3000.png}
\caption{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
\end{figure*}
```

This gives everything I need, wide and centered between the two columns but not in the results section necessarily.

PS: I'm using [twocolumn] document option

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your document, but try using [!h] instead of [h]. This is called a "bang float" and will more strongly encourage LaTeX to put your figure at a particular place. This should be avoided when possible, as you can get bad typography when overriding LaTeX's default choices.

If this doesn't work, you can try using the float package, which provides the option [H] which fixes the float in a particular spot.

You can also use the placeins package for a more complicated solution. This adds the \FloatBarrier command, which prevents figures (a type of float) from going past them. Adding the package with the command:

```latex
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

will add a FloatBarrier before every section, preventing figures from floating away from their section.